# MD5 hash special characters

Tags: c#, md5

I have tried hashing a string in PHP using MD5 and the same in C#, but the results are different if the string contains special characters. Can someone explain me how to get this matched?

Here is my code in C#:

```
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
//compute hash from the bytes of text
md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text));

//get hash result after compute it
byte[] result = md5.Hash;

StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    //change it into 2 hexadecimal digits
    //for each byte
    strBuilder.Append(result[i].ToString("x2"));
}
return strBuilder.ToString();
```

My string is `"Samuel2989&*"` as a string.

Outputs:

> PHP: 957915b9c9a8fb65e13fe1dc9a8b86d4
>
> C# : f5ee451f7eb4587da00d4aa31ae1c378

Comment: Hard to tell why it's different without seeing the PHP code.

Comment: On PHP for me, md5("Samuel2989&*"); returns the same as your C# code.

Comment: PHP generates the correct MD5 hash for me as well.

Comment: As an aside, your whole StringBuilder loop code can be replace with just: `return string.Concat(result.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));`

Comment: MD5 is a function on binary data, not strings.  The string encoding is everything, since it converts the string to the binary data that gets hashed.  The C# code above is using ASCII encoding, which for all of those characters is very well defined and doesn't depend on code pages.  Is the same string encoding algorithm being used in PHP to convert the string into binary data before being hashed?

Comment: @m.rogalski You shouldn't use tags in the text body; see, for example, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195228/when-to-use-tags-in-the-text-of-a-question-or-an-answer) for a discussion about it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this method and tell me if it worked out for you?

```
public static string MD5Hash(string input)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] bs = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        bs = x.ComputeHash(bs);
        System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in bs)
        {
            s.Append(b.ToString("x2").ToLower());
        }
        string password = s.ToString();
        return password;
    }
```

Comment: OP's C# hash is correct for that string, and PHP generates the same hash for it.

Comment: My reply does nothing to do with PHP side. @ceejayoz

Comment: @HGMamaci The point is, the OP's problem is on the PHP side so tweaking the C# code is kind of pointless.

Comment: @HGMamaci That's my point. OP's issue is not on the C# side. OP's issue is they're somehow generating the wrong MD5 hash for the string on the PHP side.

Comment: OK @ceejayoz. Accepted. Have a nice day.

Comment: @ceejayoz the problem of the OP is on C# side, he's using ASCII encoding while PHP uses as default UTF8.

Comment: @Gusman I don't believe that's the case. PHP gives the same hash as he's getting in C# when I try it. `<?= md5('Samuel2989&*') ?>` --> 
`f5ee451f7eb4587da00d4aa31ae1c378`.

Comment: @ccejayoz. That was what I thought so as well, so I gave the code with UTF8 encoding on the C# side. I had this issue with SHA1 with VPos banking key hash.

Comment: @Gusman UTF8 and ASCII give the same byte results with the characters used in the OP's string since the "special characters" are part of the standard ASCII character set.